# Is there a way to send hyperlink without embeds in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I just wanted to know if we could send a hyperlink without embeds in discord.js

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the link in `<>` tags.

For example:

```
message.channel.send("<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717956/is-there-a-way-to-send-hyperlink-without-embeds-in-discord-js>")
```